# Unable to authorize to Google Sheets v4 API from web app using javascript

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I am able to read and write data to a google sheet when running the web application on my localhost:8080 using the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) for v4 API.

When I deploy the app on external tomcat server, the authorization does not seem to happen at load

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
```

I'm running the application at `http://10.200.99.110:8080/MyApp`. In the API manager credentials I have type *'Web Application*' and Javascript origin uris' as

```
http://localhost:8080    
http://10.200.99.110:8080
```

I am a beginner to OAuth and would appreciate any help in getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was some problem in tomcat, I did a reload from the tomcat manager after deploying a new war file and it worked.

Also, I noticed that modifying javascript origin uris in Google API Credentials manager takes couple of minutes to reflect in the application.